# jQuery get json data, match the ids, then append the custom field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to retrieve json data from zendesk, then compare the value of the ids in each ticket that is retrieved from the server with the id inside my table data. If the ids match, then I want to retrieve the custom field value inside the ticket with the matching id, and append it to the table data's that i have named with the product id. The idea is to target each "td/td",and automatically insert the custom field(product id) value when a new "td/td" tag is created. Please help :) The Object 99 at the top is the ticket, the id :175 is the id I am trying to match. the custom_field array[10] value is what I want to append and display. The issue I am having is that the data is not displaying after I append it. I think this has something to do with how I am accessing the data, comparing the ids, then appending the custom field. The array value is returning a -1 instead of comparing the IDs. This is the problem.

```
//first lets get some json data!
var getjson = $.getJSON("/api/v2/tickets.json)",function (result) {
$.each(result, function(i, field) {
 console.log('data',field);

 // now lets take the text id for each td and assign it as the id.   
 $(".sort > tr > td:nth-child(1)").each(function(){

var textid = $(this).text();
  $(this).attr('id', textid);
 // if the ids match, give me the value of the custom field that is inside the     array of the matching id.     
  var arr = [field];
  var arrayvalues = $.inArray('id', arr);
 if ($(this).attr('id') == arrayvalues){

    /* if the ids match, give me the value of the 
   custom field that is inside the array of the matching id. */ 

   var returns = $.inArray('value',arr.custom_fields[i]);


 // now for each td lets append the value of the custom field.
   $(".sort > tr > td:nth-child(7)").each(function () {
    $(this).append(returns);  
   $(this).attr('id','product');
   })

 } 

  })
 });
```

Comment: Please include the contents of the console.log. :) EDIT: You've not explained the issue you have... but I assume it's because you're trying to execute code after returning your method.

Comment: I added the console.log example

Comment: You're trying to execute code after return. Return stops execution of the current method. You can't (because there's no point) assign return to anything.

Comment: I removed the return type, and data is still not appending. Is there something else i need to modify. Is there something else that i didn't. write properly. Please help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after days of knocking my head against the wall. The following code works perfectly.

```
var Obj1 = {};
var Obj2 = {};
var Obj3 = {};
var urlstring = "/api/v2/tickets/"+id+".json)";
 $.getJSON(urlstring,function (result) {
  $.each(result, function(i, value) {
Obj1[result[i].id] = result[i].fields[10].value;
Obj2[result[i].id] = result[i].fields[13].value;
Obj3[result[i].id] = result[i].fields[7].value;

console.log('Obj1', Obj1);
console.log('Obj2', Obj2);
console.log('Obj3', Obj3);
});

$.each(Obj1, function(key, element) {
$(".sort > tr").each(function(){ 
if($(this).attr('id') == key){
$(this).children('td:nth-child(7)').append(element);
 }
   });//end tr each
}); //end obj1 each
  $.each(Obj2, function(key, element) {
 $(".sort > tr").each(function(){ 
 if($(this).attr('id') == key){
 $(this).children('td:nth-child(8)').append(element);
}
 });//end tr each
}); //end obj2 each

$.each(Obj3, function(key, element) {
  $(".sort > tr").each(function(){ 
 if($(this).attr('id') == key){
 $(this).children('td:nth-child(6)').append(element);
}
 });//end tr each
}); //end obj3 each

  });//end json
```

Answer (score 0):

See `$.inArray` usage described at documentation

> **[jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray)**
>
> **value**
>
> **Type**: Anything The value to search for.
>
> **array**
>
> **Type**: Array An array through which to
>   search. fromIndex Type: Number The index of the array at which to
>   begin the search. The default is 0, which will search the whole array.

Note, also `$.inArray()`

> **Returns**: `Number`

---

Not certain about return value from `$.getJSON` ? full `json` not appear at original post ? , though see

```
$.getJSON("/api/v2/tickets.json}"
```

right bracket before closing double-quotation mark at `url` ?

---

Try changing `js` at

```
var arrayvalues = $.inArray(field).id;
```

and

```
var returns = return $.inArray(field).custom_fields('value');
```

to usage described at documentation, e.g.,

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log(
$.inArray("a", arr) // `0`
, $.inArray("b", arr) !== -1 // `true`
, $.inArray("c", arr) === 3 // `false`
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate more? I'm not sure how the usage description can be used. in replace to what I have written

Comment: @DariusCastillo `$.inArray(field).id;` not appear valid usage of `$.inArray()` . First argument to `$.inArray()` should be `value`.searched for within array ; e.g., "search for term variable `field` within ? no array specified to search at ``$.inArray(field).id;`` ? Also, `$.inArray()` does not have property, or method `id` ? , returns `Number` , _not_ value from searched array.

Comment: I have updated my code, to fix the $in.Array issue and it still doesn't work. please help. :)

Comment: @DariusCastillo Difficult to view images . Can include `json` text returned from `$.getJSON("/api/v2/tickets.json)"` ? , `html` text ?

Comment: The array value is returning a -1 instead of comparing the IDs. This is the problem.